# Issue aligning full screen subviews using interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm working on a simple application that has a RootViewController and a SubViewController. The RootViewController just loads in the fullscreen SubViewController but SubViewController isn't aligned correctly.

[image]

Notice how the UITableView is being cut off at the top of the screen.

I figure this must have something to do with the status bar as that seems to be the exact size that's being cut off. I've tried every logical combination of "simulated metrics" in interface builder but I can never get it quite right.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your viewDidLoad, not sure how you are loading things up...

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0, -20.0);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, this fixed my problem. I was stupidly trying to do this all through interface builder and didn't consider attempting to solve it in code.